# Coloring hyperlinks in 'kaobook' document class

Tags: hyperref, color, kaobook

Is there anyway to color, say blue, the theorem when we use `\ref{}` (or `\autoref{}`) to refer a theorem? For eg. look at the article: https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/nitin/papers/border-depth3.pdf

In the article, the Theorems/Lemmas/Definitions, when referred, are colored blue (for example, see page 3 --> Section 1.1 --> First paragraph last line;  "Definition A.4" and "Lemma A.21" are colored blue). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The default color for internal links in `kaobook` is black. You can set it to a different color (such as blue) with `\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}`.

Answer (score 0):

The commands are implemented in the kaorefs.sty:

```
\newcommand{\refch}[1]{\hyperref[ch:#1]{\xspace\chaptername\ref{ch:#1}}}
```

Modify these commands directly:

```
\newcommand{\refch}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\hyperref[ch:#1]{\xspace\chaptername\ref{ch:#1}}}}
```

or renew them in your tex like this:

```
\renewcommand{\refch}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\hyperref[ch:#1]{\xspace\chaptername\ref{ch:#1}}}}
```

Comment: Per my view, altering default tag may cause some serious issue, better to suggest `\hypersetup` tag